# delete() not working on laravel 8 controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

My Laravel Project have a resource controller named `Blogpost`, where in destroy method, the `$blogpost->delete()` approach doesn't work. But if I use DB Query, it works just fine. See code below.

**This doesn't work:**

```
public function destroy(Blogpost $blogpost)
{
    $blogpost->delete();
    
    return redirect()->route('blog.index');
}
```

**This works perfectly:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Blogpost::find($id); 
    $post->delete();

    return redirect()->route('blog.index');
}
```

In routes\web.php, I'm using resource route for this controller.

```
Route::resource('blog', BlogpostController::class);
```

**Note:** The Blogpost model have a hasMany() relationship with postViews model.

```
public function postViews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostViews::class);
}
```

Note: `post_views` table have a foreign key associate with blogpost table. See migration below:

```
$table->foreign('blogpost_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('blogposts')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
```

If I use `dd($blogpost);` it returns the model.

code:

```
public function destroy(Blogpost $blogpost)
{
    dd($blogpost);
}
```

Output:

[image: dd() inside destroy method]

**My question is, why `$blogpost->delete();` approach is not working? is it because of the hasMany() relationship?**

PS: I have another resource controller named Category, where the `$category->delete()` approach works perfectly.

Comment: I guess your route parameter is called {id} and `$blogpost` is null? do you get an error? Try to `dd($blogpost)`

Comment: Hi @gert b,  I'm using resource route. code: Route::resource('blog', BlogpostController::class);

Comment: did you `dd($blogpost)`? Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi @GertB. I just did dd($blogpost), it returns App\Models\Blogposts. See this screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/GE40GYY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Change your `destroy` method to be:

```
public function destroy(Blogpost $blog)
{
    $blog->delete();
    
    return redirect()->route('blog.index');
}
```

I would imagine the reason this is happening is because your route parameter is `blog` but your controller  parameter is `$blogpost` i.e. they don't match.

If you type hint a controller method parameter, Laravel will try and resolve **an** instance of it out of the container. This is why you get an instance of `Blogpost` but not the loaded instance you want. [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) won't work here because the names have to match.

Answer (score 0):

You did't set model in controller. And your output in **attributes** and **original** is **null**, so you can't delete the post. Now, first remove **controller** and **model** then run below command and then try delete method:

```
php artisan make:controller BlogpostController --resource --model=Blogpost
```

[image]