# Nothing any update with put method in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm currently creating a simple todo-list in Laravel 8 and want to be able to update the items of the list.
My code doesn't get any error but also nothing changes when I put the submit button.

index.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('index.update', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   <td><input type="text" name="content" value="{{ $task->content }}" id=""></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
</form>
```

web.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TaskController;

Route::resource('index', TaskController::class);
```

TaskController.php:

```
public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $request->validate([
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);
    $task->update($request->all());

    return redirect('index');
}
```

Comment: This is because your `Route::resource()` is using `index`, however, your method is using `task` which don't match. Please look at this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250250/delete-not-working-on-laravel-8-controller/69252787#69252787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rwd said, the problem is with the route definition. Change it to:

```
Route::resource('tasks', TaskController::class);
```

Then in the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.update', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
```